# How to copy logfiles between two dates into a file with logfile date as extension

Tags: linux, bash, user-interface

```
Get_Timelog() 
{ 
    dialog --backtitle "Welcome" --title "Get Timelog" \ 
        --calendar "Please choose a start date..." 0 0 1 1 2013 2>/tmp/dat1.$$ 
    retval=$? 
    dat1=`cat /tmp/dat1.$$` 
    if [ $retval = 0 ] ; then 
        dialog --calendar "Please choose an end date" 0 0  5 1 2013 2>/tmp/dat2.$$ 
        rtval=$? 
        dat2=`cat /tmp/dat2.$$` 
        if [ $rtval = 0 ] ; then 
            dialog --inputbox "please enter a filename to save" 50 40 2>/tmp/input.$$ 
            na=`cat /tmp/input.$$` 
            date '+%b' -d "$dat1" 
            for i in $(ls); do 
                less $i | grep  “$dat1|$dat2” >$na."$date" 
            done 

        else 
            echo " cancel is pressed " 
        fi 
    else 
        echo " cancel is pressed " 
    fi
}
```

I am using this code but it's not working. If I select two dates as apr1 and apr4 and test as file name, there should be four files created as test.apr1,test.apr2.test.apr3 and test.apr4.

Comment: Hi, your post would be much better readable if you fixed your indentation. Here's some information about how the formatting works: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: When you say it is not working, in what way is it not working?  What do you get instead?  Have you run it in debug mode (`bash -x script.sh`)?

Comment: i need the logic i have tried this logic on my own i guess some mistakes are there in my code can anyone give me a correct logic for this task i would appreciate it.

Comment: the log files are present in a directory for ex say work as a directory there are ten log files i used grep to search with date ( grep -E $date1|$date2 ) as i said in the question if i give 3 dates 3 files should be created with date name ( for Ex Apr1) as extension, somehow iam missing something which iam not able to figure it out. if anyone who are experts in scripting can help me i would appreciate it Thanks in advance

Comment: no one understand my question? i have 10 log files in a directory i created a Graphical user interface to select the dates from user if user selects two dates , i need to read every file in directory as an input and lines corresponding to the give dates should be copied in to a file with date given as extension